Snakemake InputFunctionException TypeError: all() takes no keyword arguments
I am currently stuck on running my snakemake and not understanding where the error may be coming from.
This is the error message I get.
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided remote nodes: 21
Job stats:
job                 count
----------------  -------
BaseRecalibrator        2
all                     1
total                   3

Select jobs to execute...
InputFunctionException in rule BaseRecalibrator in file /cluster/home/me/WES/workflow/rules/align.smk, line 104:
Error:
  TypeError: all() takes no keyword arguments

align.smk from line 104

rule BaseRecalibrator:
  input:
    bam="/cluster/projects/lab/WES/alignment/{sample}/{sample}.sortfixtag.bam"
  output:
    metrics="/cluster/projects/lab/WES/alignment/{sample}/{sample}.recal_data.csv"
  params:
    ref = config['ref_index']['genome'],
    dbsnp = config['snvdb']['dbsnp'],
    dbmills = config['snvdb']['indels'],
    dbindel = config['snvdb']['indels2']
  threads: 21
  shell:
    """
    module load gatk/4.2.5.0
    
    gatk --java-options "-Xmx25g" \
      BaseRecalibrator \
      -R {params.ref} \
      -I {input.bam} \
      --use-original-qualities \
      -O {output.metrics} \
      --known-sites {params.dbsnp} \
      --known-sites {params.dbmills} \
      --known-sites {params.dbindel}
    """

Snakefile
workdir: "/cluster/home/me/WES"

##### load rules #####
include: "rules/common.smk"
include: "rules/align.smk"

##### target rules #####
rule all:
  input:
    expand("/cluster/projects/lab/WES/alignment/{sample}/{sample}.recal_data.csv", sample=samples["sample_name"])

Config.yaml
ref_index:
  bwa-index: "/cluster/projects/lab/data/genomes_BWA"
  genome: "/cluster/projects/lab/data/genomes_BWA/GCA_000001405.29_GRCh38.p14_genomic.fa"
 
snvdb:
  dbsnp: "/cluster/projects/lab/data/snv_indel_db/dbsnp/All_20180418.vcf.gz"
  indels: "/cluster/projects/lab/data/snv_indel_db/indels2/Mills_and_1000G_gold_standard.indels.hg38.vcf.gz"
  indels2: "/cluster/projects/lab/data/snv_indel_db/indels/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.known_indels.vcf.gz"

Can someone please help me to figure out where this error is stemming from?
Thank you.

This post makes me wonder if the issue may be in the params directive, for which you don't provide any details about what is referenced there?

Thank you for the comment. I have added my config.yaml file to the post, which defines params.

I was hoping there was something obvious there, but not seeing such a thing from that. Are you able to replace the params in any way to rule out if it is due to that or not?

What happens if you paste the content of "rules/common.smk" and "rules/align.smk" in your snakefile instead of using include? Where does your samples dict come from?

I'm with @Wayne on this - it looks like an item in your config dictionary being used as a parameter to the rule somehow contains a reference to the all() function (the Python global, not your "all" rule). Replacing the config values with strings as a test should show if this is the case. You can also dump the config - import pprint ; exit(pprint.pformat(config)) at the end of your Snakefile.
